# Auto fetch data from website iOS/iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I wanted to auto fetch data(gold price) from a website and update a variable. Do i have to load the whole .html file in a string and find the price? Is there any other way? Even if I updated the variable, how do i save it, so it retains it's  updated value(price)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do i have to load the whole .html file
>   in a string and find the price?

Yes

> Is there any other way?

Only if the web site also provides an API that gives you access to just the data you need.

> Even if I updated the variable, how do
>   i save it, so it retains it's updated
>   value(price)?

A variable will keep it's value until you change it. However if you want to preserve it even when the user quits your app, so that it starts again from the same value, you  could save it in [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for example.

Do be aware however, that the data is almost certainly copyright, you can't just scrape data from a website and publish an app based on that data without considering the legal perspective. Price data is normally owned by the exchange and you will need a license to re-publish it.

Comment: thanks roger. The owner of the site wants me to use the information from their site. is using stringWithContentsOfURL the right way of getting all the HTML and then process it? Or is there a way just to get text off the site?

Comment: If you want to get all the HTML and then process it, stringWithContentsOfURL is OK, but it would probably be better to use an Asynchronous method of fetching the data (see the third party ASIHTTPRequest library which makes this a doddle, or use NSURLConnection and manage it yourself). This then lets you receive the data in chunks and you don't have to hold it all in memory at once. You may decide that the html is pretty short so having it all in at once is no problem, and that's cool, but do consider an asynchronous way of fetching it as that will make the UI better.